# Processing a 100MB file in Node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, query-string, filestream

Basically I have a file, say, `100mb.qs` and I need to pass its entire contents through the following function:

```
function process(in){
  var out = JSON.stringify(require('querystring').parse(in));
  return out;
}
```

And then replace the file's contents with the result.

I imagine that I'll have to stream it, so...

```
require('fs').createReadStream('1mb.qs').pipe( /* ??? */ )
```

What to I do?

Comment: Streaming isn't very useful here, considering that the querystring module isn't a stream parser and requires the entire object to be loaded to memory.

Comment: write your own streaming querysting module

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `clarinet` for parsing `JSON` as a stream.

```
var createReadStream = require('fs').createReadStream
, createWriteStream = require('fs').createReadStream
, parseJson = require('clarinet').createStream()
;

parseJson.on('error', function(err){
  if (err) throw err
})

parseJson.on('onvalue', function(v){
  // do stuff with value 
})

parseJson.on('onopenobject', function (key) {
  // I bet you got the idea how this works :)
})

createReadStream('100mb.qs')
  .pipe(parseJson)
  .pipe(createWriteStream('newerFile.qs'))
```

there is many more events to listen to, so you definitely show take a look.
Also, it will send data down stream whenever a JSON node is ready to be written. It couldn't get better then this.

Hope this helps